# Sort numerical only part of the file bash

Tags: bash, sorting, numeric

my input file is:

```
b; 1 ; b; 1
a; 5 ; a; 5
g; 2 ; g; 2
```

i would like an output:

```
b; 1 ; b; 1
a; 5 ; g; 2
g; 2 ; a; 5
```

Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: How did you get from input to output?  Can you expand on "Sort numerical only part of the file bash"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ paste -d';' <(cut -d';' -f1,2 file) <( cut -d';' -f3,4 file | sort -t';' -n -k2)
b; 1 ; b; 1
a; 5 ; g; 2
g; 2 ; a; 5
```

#### How it works

This selects the first two columns from the input file:

```
$ cut -d';' -f1,2 file
b; 1
a; 5
g; 2
```

This selects the second two columns from the input file and then sorts them numerically on the last column:

```
$ cut -d';' -f3,4 file | sort -t';' -n -k2
 b; 1
 g; 2
 a; 5
```

This uses process substitution, `<(...)`, to `paste` the two parts back together:

```
$ paste -d';' <(cut -d';' -f1,2 file) <( cut -d';' -f3,4 file | sort -t';' -n -k2)
b; 1 ; b; 1
a; 5 ; g; 2
g; 2 ; a; 5
```